# Find the number of n-long sequences of complex numbers that form the beginning of some $\lambda$ -sequence.

Tags: solution-verification, complex-numbers

A $\lambda$ sequence is an infinite sequence of complex numbers, so if the Culver sequence operator deletes all the 0s and replaces each remaining number x with

$x - 3 + \frac{1}{x}$

then it gets the same sequence it started with.

Find the number of n-long sequences of complex numbers that form the beginning of some $\lambda$ -sequence.

My attempt

Trivially , in our case we have 0
So here we call the transformation
T(x) = x - 3 + 1/x
Except the sequence being produced using 0s
There is another trivially noticable sequence where T(x) = x , which has only 1 solution , x = 1/3.
So now we have obtained a trivial sequence of 1/3s as one of our solutions.
Next we have The original sequence being created by 0s.

**Case 1** : Simple Branching

First element, 0
Second Element , T(x) = 0
Third Element , T(T(x)) = 0
Nth element T(T(T....n times) = 0
We can assure that during selection of every element we will have 2 choices , as T(x) is of a quadratic nature if x is not 0
Thus , having 2 options starting from 2nd elements , the number of sequences we can make are 2^(n-1) for sequences of n length.

**Case 2**: Multiple Branches:

Element 1 : 0
Element 2 : 0
Elemenr 3 : T(x) = 0 (Root 1)
Elemenr 3 : T(x) = 0 (Root 2)
Here we can easily see that if we are counting the above sequence , we always get a choice between 2 roots of T(x) = element n - 2 , if sequence size is greater than or equal to 4 , thus , for n >= 4 ,
We have 2^(n-3) sequences here.
Trivial Case : 1/3 , its just 1 sequence where 1/3 is just repeated.
Trivial Case 2: Maxima Use Of Roots
Sequence utilizes all the roots to create an ultimate sequence. , Only 1 such sequence is possible , that too for n > 3.
So , we get a total of 2^(n-1)+2^(n-3)+2 for all n >= 4
and for remaining n values
n = 1 -> 1
n = 2 -> 3
n = 3 -> 5
n = 4 -> 12